# Where is the color setting for the Active Symbol Highlighting Feature in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

Anytime my cursor is on a symbol or keyword VS2013 (or some plugin i have) highlights all matches of those instances:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/t2jHsyhG]

[image: http://screencast.com/t/9F90AysQZuCI]

I don't mind the highlighting; however, this exact color is annoying with the sons-of-obsidian theme (or any dark background).

I would love to know which setting under Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors controls this so that i can fix it... (As far as I can tell, none of the options adjust it, which makes me think it could be one of the plugins i have...

Plugins:
Resharper 8.2 (does adjust colors, but none of the settings I've changed worked)
Nuget Package Manager (shouldn't adjust colors)
MVC 5 Scaffolding (shouldn't adjust colors)
Nancy.Templates (shouldn't adjust colors)
Puppet Plugin (shouldn't adjust colors)
Visual F# (shouldn't adjust colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong, it was not the stupid VS2013 Update 2 RC, it seems to have been the "Puppet" plugin I had installed, I must've disabled it and not restarted visual studio until removing the update 2 RC, This is the setting that took me forever to find.... I glossed over it because i'm in a C# file and not a puppet file.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem with another extension messing with colors except mine was something in Productivity Power Tools that disappeared when I disabled, restarted, then re-enabled it.

Answer (score 8):

This is built in functionality provided by Visual Studio. To turn it off click on `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced` and turn off `Highlight references to symbol under cursor`
[image]

If you only want to change the colors you can do this by `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors` and in the `Display Items` list search for `Highlighted Reference`.
[image]

Comment: I tried both of these, the first did not actually disable and the latter did not change the color... perhaps i found some odd... will try again and start disabling other stuff to see if that works.

Comment: @Rob Yes. I would try to unload/disable ReSharper first.

Comment: @Rob: Did this answer help after you disabled ReSharper?

Comment: no, i disabled all plugins, and turned off "Highlight references to symbols under cursor" and still get the same result. My next step is to check to see if have a "beta" service pack installed...

Comment: @Rob: Also see if changing the theme makes a difference with the settings. Which type of VS 2013 are you using?

Comment: Using VS2013 Pro @ Home (Ultimate at work) - I do not have this issue at work, I'm going to try exporting all of my settings from there and apply them to my home machine and see what happens...

Comment: I exported my theme from work and applied it at home, where i do have Update 2 RC installed. It seems to be a bug with Update 2 RC, removing it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is a resharper setting. Unfortunately, there's so many different settings for various types of highlighting, I can't figure out which is which. Have you tried [this modified version](https://github.com/elerch/Visual-Studio-Settings/blob/master/son-of-obsidian-for-resharper.vssettings) of Sons of Obsidian?

Comment: Yeah, tried that variation as well as changing every setting I could find... None seem to fix it.

Comment: How about "Highlighted Reference"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in 2023. To turn off the highlihgting alltogether, go to ReSharper settings > code inspection > settings > uncheck 'highlight usages of the element under the cursor'.

Alternatively, the highlight color can be changed by going to the VS Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors and finding the entry in the list called: '**ReSharper Usage of element under cursor**'.

Comment: Hi Dorstlesser, thanks for the answer. However, in this instance the author of the question had actually posted their own answer.  The highlighting was done by Puppet, not Resharper.  They also accepted their own answer.

It's always a good idea to check other answers, and especially check for an accepted answer (green tick below it).  Only post a new answer if you're confident the accepted answer is wrong, or you've more to give.

Thanks again for your submission though. Keep posting answers!