# Visual Studio Reference Highlighting Won't Disable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fonts, visual-studio-2013, highlighting

I have disabled Reference Highlighting in Visual Studio 2013 for C# code using the instructions here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/18/visual-studio-2013-reference-highlighting.aspx. Yet, I still see references highlighted.

The font-color combination being used does not match the font-color setting for Highlighted Reference -- the setting is green background with off-white text, and highlighted references appear as white background with off-white text. Also, the reference navigation does not work (as expected) -- pressing CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN/UP does not do anything, indicating the highlighted references feature is turned off.

How can I stop the references from being highlighted?

Comment: Do you have any other addins that may be doing this (e.g. ReSharper)?

Comment: Also check if you have the Puppet plugin. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23258908/3499063

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was caused by the Match Margin feature of the Productivity Power Tools extension. I couldn't find a way to change the background color used for highlighting, so I just turned off the feature.

Comment: Under [Menu]Tools/Options then Environment/Fonts & Colors/Highlighted Reference you can choose a color to match the background. It still draws a box around the reference.

Comment: The "Match color" display item controls the highlights from Power Tools, though it does seem to be overwritten when VS Highlight References is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

> On the Tools menu, click Options. In the Options dialog box, expand
>   Text Editor, and then complete one of the following tasks: For Visual
>   Basic, expand Basic, click VB Specific, and then select or clear
>   Enable highlighting of references and keywords. For C#, expand C#,
>   click Advanced, and then select or clear Highlight references to
>   symbol under cursor.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349251(v=vs.100).aspx